# Difference between push and assignment in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

```
async getModifiedData() {
  let dbData = await dbdata.getData();
  
  let fileData = [];

  dbData.map(data => {
    fileData[data["uniquePropertyName"]] = data;
  });

  return fileData; // here I'm getting empty array
}
```

Whereas I get filled array when using `push()` method,

```
async getModifiedData() {
  let dbData = await dbdata.getData();
  
  let fileData = [];

  dbData.map(data => {
    let propertyName = data["uniquePropertyName"];
    let obj = {};
    obj[propertyName] = data;
    fileData.push(obj);
  });

  return fileData; // here I'm getting filled array
}
```

Both are working correct when the array size is small but for larger array, `Array.push()` only returns filled array. Can anyone explain what's happening here.

Comment: Please don't use `.map()` for doing single iteration. Use `.forEach()` or a simple loop.

Comment: @VLAZ In this case `.map()` would be the right tool, when not used in the wrong way... `fileData = dbData.map(data => /*...*/ return obj)`

Comment: Arrays are special objects. All objects support assignment to arbitrary property names. Assignment to arbitrary property names _does not_ automatically insert those values into the special iterable collection we think of when we refer to an array's contents.

Comment: The first example doesn't look right to me. Is `data["uniquePropertyName"]` returning a unique index (= number)? Otherwise `fileData` should be an object and not an array (and `map()` should be `.forEach()`)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign something to an array or and object, but the way you do it is different.
If you're assigning something to an array, you should be using an index (though @tehhowch's answer is correct, but we never assign values to an array in the same way we do to an object). If you're assigning something to an object, you should be using key values (which are normally, though not always, strings).

Also, as others have mentioned, .map returns a new array after doing something with each element in another array. .map requires a value to be returned. .forEach is just a shorter way of writing a for loop; it will go over every value in an array (or any iterable object) and do something, but it doesn't require that something be returned and something *can't* be returned.

.push simply pushes something into an array (into the end, not the beginning)

Examples below for clarity.

```
//.map
const example = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const exampleDoubled = example.map(number => {
  return number * 2;
});
console.log(exampleDoubled);
//expected output: [2, 4, 6, 8]

//.forEach
example.forEach(number => {
  //for each number, do something
  console.log(number);

  // no return value needed
});
//expected output:
//1
//2
//3
//4

//Assigning to an array
const newArray = Array(3);
newArray[0] = 1;
newArray[1] = 2;
newArray[2] = 3;
console.log(newArray);
//expected output: [1, 2, 3]
//Notice that we're assigning using indexes because we're dealing with an array


//Assigning to an object
const newObject = {};
newObject['anyKey'] = "any value. does not have to be a string";
newObject['someOtherKey'] = function() { //do stuff };
console.log(newObject);
//expected output:
// {
// 'anyKey': "any value. does not have to be a string",
// 'someOtherKey': [Function]
//}

//.push
const myArray = [1, 2, 3];
myArray.push(4);
console.log(myArray);
//expected output: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What I'm guessing you want with your code (I don't know what the data looks like, so I can't give you an exact answer);

```
async getModifiedData() {
  let dbData = await dbdata.getData();
  
  let fileData = dbData.map(data => {
    return data["uniquePropertyName"];
    //assuming here that data is an object and you want an array
    //of a particular value from these objects
  });

  return fileData;
}
```

Hope this helps! You can always check out MDN and W3Schools documentation for more information.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 1):

To simplify, there are several different issues in your code, but I'll focus on why the first example does not actually populate the array:

In JavaScript, you can put values in an array by assigning directly to the array slot using a numeric index in square brackets - even if that index was not used before:

```js
var a = [];
a[2] = 'foo';
console.log(a.length); // => 3
```

You can also put values into object fields by assigning directly to the object field using the name of the field in square brackets:

```js
var a = {};
a['foo'] = 'bar';
```

As you can see the syntax is identical. Also - you have to remember that in Javascript - everything is an object, including arrays. You can say that arrays are object that are specialized by understanding that fields whose name are numeric affect the array length and iteration content.

So your first example doesn't actually handle `fileData` as an array - it treats it as an object that was coincidentally initialized as an empty array. After you set all the *additional non-numeric* fields, the array is still empty. (That is assuming that the `uniquePropertyName` field contains text and not a number - if it does sometimes contains a number then that would explain why "sometimes it works").

Comment: BTW, a common way to add elements to the and of an array, other than `push()`, is to assign a value to the index one larger than the last index: `a[a.length] = "value"`